# What are the difference between these React Native start commands?

Tags: react-native

I have been using react native for a couple months now. However, I really don't know the difference between the starting commands. Currently, I use npm on my project. However, I know yarn can be used. These are the commands I really don't understand the difference with:

exp start, exp ios, exp android

react-native run-ios, react-native run-android

npm start, npm ios, npm android

Which ones are better in what cases and why? Currently, I am using exp but others use react-native run-ios. I used to use npm ios.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might help to have an overview of the [React Native architecture](https://www.reactnative.guide/3-react-native-internals/3.1-react-native-internals.html).

In react native, when you write, say, `<View/>`, it gets sent across the bridge to the native code and dynamically translated into `UIView` on iOS or `android.view.View` on Android. Every basic component in the `react-native` package has been implemented this way. If you want additional native functionality on both platforms, say a library which uses native map components, you will end up having to include the native libraries separately into your Android `build.gradle` and your iOS `.xcodeproj`.

The `exp` CLI is used to start apps built with the [Expo SDK](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/workflow/exp-cli). Expo is essentially a prebuilt app with a certain set of native components already included for convenience; all you supply is your JSX; thus the recommendation to "eject" to a regular react native app if you need to use any other libraries.

`react-native run-ios` and `run-android` builds the native `.app` or `.apk` using the iOS or Android toolchains, starts the Metro Bundler, which minifies and serves the JSX and other assets such as images over to your device in debug mode (You might see something like `Loading from localhost:8081`).

On Android, it starts the `adb` server to push the APK with all the native libraries included onto your device, if you have USB debugging enabled. `run-ios` does the same with the `.app`; if you install to a simulator it has automatically configured `AppDelegate.m` to communicate with `localhost:8081`, whereas live reload over USB has to be configured manually on a physical device.

`react-native start` simply starts the Metro bundler, which is useful if you already have the app installed.

Commands that begin with `npm` are defined as scripts in your `package.json` file. As of RN 0.57, `npm start` simply calls `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`; which is the same as running `react-native start`; [according to the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/understanding-cli) `react-native-cli` installed separately will call the locally installed version of the CLI in `node_modules`.

Comment: what about "yarn android"?